# How to call javascript function from a controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have looked round and I cannot find a solutions hence I find myself here. from what i have read i  would been able to do this in asp.net web forms using RegisterClientScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock. I cannot find this in any MVC3 documentation.
I have  the following function in a MVC 3 View :

MyTest View :

```
<div data-role="content">

<div id="mappingTable"></div>

</div>

 </section>
 @section Scripts {
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#jqm-home").live('pageinit', function () {
        addTableRow(' adding data to table <br/>');
    });

    //I want to the able to call the function from the controller.
    function addTableRow(msg) {
        $('#mappingTable').append(msg);        
    }; 

   </script>
 }
```

In My Controller I have the following.

```
public class MyTestController : Controller
    {
      #region Class Constractor

       public MyTestController()
       {            
           Common.ControllerResourceEvent += new System.EventHandler<ResourceEventArgs>(Common_ResourceEvent);
       }

    private void Common_ResourceEvent(object sender, ResourceEventArgs e)
    {
        //I want to call the function addTableRow and pass ResourceEventArgs 
    } 

    #endregion Class Constractor      

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the client to call the server, or vice versa?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Call a server on a button click, which then calls the client? Why not just use AJAX to call the server, then in the callback you can call your function.

Answer (score 10):

You can't really "call" the client Javascript from the controller. What you can do, assuming you want to do something analogous to RegisterClientScript which is injecting JS code into your page, can be done pretty easily. You can either create a model (which is nothing more than a simple class) that has a string property on it. Set the property value to the client-side JS code that you want to inject. Pass the model to the view. In your View, reference the property - something like this:

```
public class SampleModel
{
   public string JS { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SampleModel();
    model.JS = "addTableRow('My Message');";
    return View(model);
}

// In the view (at the top - note the cast of "model" and "Model"
@model Namespace.SampleModel
// Then your script 
<script type="text/javascript">
   @Model.JS
```

Or, if you don't want to create model, you can pass it via the ViewBag, which is a dynamic object:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.JS = "addTableRow('My Message');";
    return View();
}

// In the view:
<script type="text/javascript">
   @ViewBag.JS
```

Comment: `@ViewBag.JS` might cause a syntax error. If that's the case try `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.JS)`

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScriptModel ( http://jsm.codeplex.com ) you could do it the following way:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.AddJavaScriptFunction("addTableRow", "My Message");
    return View();
}
```

It would be even better if you create a js-file with a function and add the Tables as list to a js variable. The js function will then iterate over the list and add the tables.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.AddJavaScriptVariable("TableListInJavaScript", tableList);
    this.AddJavaScriptFunction("MyTableReadyFunction");
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be coming from things at the wrong angle here. You can't call javascript on a page directly from a controller. You can only do things the other way around, i.e. call a controller method from javascript, using ajax, there are several jquery ajax functions to help you do this. The most useful one being $.post()

A pattern I use most often is the following :

in web page :

```
$.post('TestController/TestGetPartialView','{param1:"string to add"}', function (data) {

    ('#mappingTable').append(data); // this adds the string to the mapping table.

},'html');
```

in controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult TestGetPartialView(string param1)
{   
   return PartialView("TestPartial", param1);
}
```

in partial view :

```
@model string
<p> Model </p>
```

This will pass a string from the page back to the controller, onto the partial view then back to the page. This might not be exactly what you want to do but it's an example of how to pass data around using ajax and partial views which I think might help you.