# How to call JavaScript function from controller in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building through a problem i.e. How could I call JavaScript function through my controller,i am basically using `scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock` but the code is error full which prevents me to proceed, i dont want to go with JSON or any plugins only I want simple JavaScript calling logic,here you go for the code please

```
                        {
                            Session["UserDetails"] = strConCat;
                            Session["objLoginUser"] = objUser;
                            string strScript = "AlertConfirmRe();";---------//This is my JScript function
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "TEST", strScript, true);                                                                
            return;
                        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from a controller in MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166235/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-a-controller-in-mvc3)